# Unexpected behaviour while working with two-dimensional arrays in C (getting random numbers inside it)

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void printMatrix(int x, int y, int **matrix)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void fillMatrix(int **array, int x, int y)
{
    int i, j;
    for ( i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        array[i] = (int*)malloc(x * sizeof(int));
        printf("Fill in the row No.%d of matrix\n", i+1);
        for ( j = 0; j < x; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int **a, **b, size, i, j;
    printf("Give the size of matrix a: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    a = (int**)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    fillMatrix(a, size, size);
    printMatrix(size, size, a);
    printf("Give the size of matrix b: ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    b = (int**)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    fillMatrix(b, size, size);
    printMatrix(size, size, b);
    free(a);
    free(b);
    return 0;
}
```

The function `fillMatrix()` reads the inputs from the user and then write them to the matrix, the function `printMatrix()` as the name suggests - prints it to the console. Don't know exactly what's the problem, but in my console log the first elements of matrices are altered to some random big numbers. Here is the console log:

[image: Console Log]

Comment: `a = (int**)malloc(size * sizeof(int));` is wrong, change to `a = (int**)malloc(size * sizeof(int*));`. On most modern systems, pointers are 8 bytes, `int`s are 4 bytes, so `sizeof(int)` won't give you enough space. You want your `sizeof` parameter to be "one level up of abstraction" from the pointer you're allocating for. Likewise for `b`.

Comment: A preferred way [by many] to do this is: `a = malloc(size * sizeof(*a));` If you should change [at a later date] the type of `a`, all such `malloc` calls will automatically adapt without having to change each instance by hand.

Comment: YourLogarithm, `int **matrix` is a pointer perhaps to an array, of `int *` (another pointer). "working with two-dimensional arrays" implies a goal of _two-dimensional array_.  Do you want to follow the title or the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix is not the two-dimensional array only an array of pointers.

```
void printMatrix(size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*array)[cols])
{
    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            printf("%6d", array[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void fillMatrix(size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*array)[cols])
{
    for (size_t row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            array[row][col] = row * 10 + col;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    size_t rows,cols;
    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    if(scanf("%zu", &rows) != 1) {/* hanle error */ };
    printf("\nEnter number of columns: ");
    if(scanf("%zu", &cols) != 1) {/* hanle error */ };
    printf("\n");

    int (*array)[rows][cols] = malloc(sizeof(*array));

    if(!array) {/* hanle error */ };


    fillMatrix(rows, cols, array);
    printMatrix(rows, cols, array);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7EM58x7ca